# perl cgi talks to javascript

Tags: javascript, database, perl, cgi, xss

I want to retrieve a csv file from one online database. However, due to some XSS issues, I cant directly use ajax, but need to relay on a perl-cgi file.

I already had a working perl-cgi file that can query the csv file , and write the content of the file into a perl variable called $text. Here are some code snippets:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use CGI;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
use LWP::UserAgent; 

# construct cgi object
my $q = CGI->new;


# create a post request
my $useragent = LWP::UserAgent->new();  
my $request = POST '.....', [ 
     #something goes here
];
my $response = $useragent->request($request);
my $text = $response->content; 

print $text;
```

I have some general ideas of what to do next, but not so sure about the details. I will upload this perl-cgi file to the server that hosts my website, to the folder called cgi-bin. I just wonder how can I call that perl-cgi file from javascript, and write back the content of $text into javascript varaiable.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is a client-side language, while Perl is a server-side language. This means that you won't be able to directly read the value of a Perl variable into Javascript.

What you *can* do is have the Perl script output the results of its operations. Your Javascript then calls this Perl script via AJAX and reads the result.

Here's some pseudocode to illustrate what I mean:

**Perl script: csv_worker.cgi**

```
// retrieve csv file into $text as per OP

print "Content-type: text/csv\n\n";
print $text;
```

**Javascript**

```
function request() {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // Supports newer browsers
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // Supports older IE versions (IE 5/IE 6)
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","csv_worker.cgi",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Hi Jared Ng, I just tried, at least I got something printed this time, but why instead of showing me the csv file, it shows ... the content of perl file. Did i miss anything?

Comment: @Josh It sounds like your web server is not configured to interpret the Perl file as an executable script. Are you sure that your Perl file is in the configured "cgi-bin" directory of your web server? If you're using Apache, check your httpd.conf

Comment: @ Jared, I use command line (from SSH secure shell) to execute the perl-cgi file, it does print out the values of csv files. I have a doubt: should I place the cgi-bin folder inside public_htm, or at the same the directory? Thanks

Comment: It should be in whichever directory your web server is configured to execute cgi scripts. Check your server configuration.

Comment: I will do, but if I can execute the perl-cgi file from command lines (as I stated above), that means my server is correctly configured , right?

Comment: No. Whether or not a file is executable at the file system level is determined by the operating system. Whether or not a file is executable when accessed from the web is a characteristic managed by the web server.